# Using gulp with Laravel Elixir - disable tray icon messages?

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

When I use `gulp` with Laravel Elixir tasks in it using the command line on Windows, every time it runs messages are displayed in a tray icon. I *have* to click on the text-balloons to make `gulp` finish its tasks. I find this very annoying.

What is causing this tray icon to appear on Windows, and how to disable it, or make it not necessary to click on the balloon ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Disable gulp-notify**
>
> If you are running on a system that handles
>   notifications poorly or you simply do not wish to use gulp-notify but
>   your project does? You can disable gulp-notify by using enviroment
>   variable DISABLE_NOTIFIER.
>
> export DISABLE_NOTIFIER=true; This will disable all methods; notify(),
>   notify.onError and notify.withReporter.

You can read more about it in [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-notify#disable-gulp-notify)

So if you want to disable your gulp notifications just add this to your gulp file, before requiring laravel-elixir.

```
process.env.DISABLE_NOTIFIER = true;
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
```

You can read more about it in this [issue](https://github.com/laravel/elixir/issues/284)